# How to moving your developed workflow solution one server to another server?

Tags: list, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2007, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-workflow

How to moving workflow one server to another server ?
i mean how do you deploy workflow solution file one site to another site.

Comment: What kind of solution file do you have? Wsp solution? If so you can install like any other wsp solution.

Comment: yes Wsp .   Yevgeniy.Chernobrivets..!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use powershell to deploy wsp solutions. First you need to call Add-SPSolution cmdlet to add wsp solution to solution store and then deploy it using Install-SPSolution cmdlet. Please refer to [this](http://patrickboom.wordpress.com/2010/05/31/using-powershell-to-deploy-sharepoint-solutions-wsp-2/) post.

Example:

```
Add-SPSolution “D:\Deploy\MySharePointSolution.wsp“
Install-SPSolution –Identity MySharePointSolution.wsp –WebApplication http://myspwebapp –GACDeployment
```

Comment: Okay. Thank you Yevgeniy.Chernobrivets..!